# Cancelling SQL request from ASP.net page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, multithreading

I've spent a week trying to resolve this problem. The idea is I need to have 2 buttons, "Execute" and "cancel". "Execute" runs a long SQL query. Cancel must be able to "cancel" the query. The problem is that when I send 2 ajax queries to the server, they are done sequentially, so the "cancel" click handler function can not "cancel" the previous one( though I have a query on which I can call Q.cancel() ). I see this is related to "locking the Session".

I was even unable to redirect user to another webpage when "cancel" is clicked, because the ajax call for "execute" does not allow anything else to be executed until it's finished.

I've tried using microsoft's reactive extensions(rx.net) library, which may allow me to create another thread for "execute", but in this case as I'm not waiting for that thread to finish and return, I don't get the query results back.

Please help. Any help except saying "Don't cancel it" is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, requests should be handled on separate threads from the thread pool. It sounds like you're using IISExpress or somehow limiting your thread count on IIS to 1.

As well as investigating your IIS settings, you're encouraged to use [asynchronous handlers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx) for long-running requests as they don't hog threads. This would allow a single thread to handle both the Execute and Cancel requests although you will have to store a `CancellationToken` somewhere like the Session state.